# continuously fetch data from a blocking queue

Tags: java, concurrency

we want to fetch a continuous stream of data from a blocking queue.

follow scenario: a pipeline, consisting of multiple stages, connected via linked blocking queues, drains all processed data into a last blocking queue. the arrival of data is not ensured to be on time (or to express it in a better way: data might arrive in bursts).

a consumer shall read from the pipe in a non-blocking way. read data, if data is present, if no data is present, assume zero ( digit: 0) values. what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: [`poll` the queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll()), check for `null`, and use zero if it is.

Comment: obviously. that's it. thanks. (could you please put this as answer, so i can mark it as resolved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`poll` the queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll()), check for `null`, and use zero if it is:

```
Integer valueFromQueue = queue.poll();
int valueToUse = (valueFromQueue != null) ? valueFromQueue : 0;
```

If you're using Guava, you can simplify this syntax using [`MoreObjects.firstNonNull`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull-T-T-):

```
int valueToUse = MoreObjects.firstNonNull(queue.poll(), 0);
```